# How do I perform javascript activity using the values from database?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I wish to change the color of the dots as red, blue and green depending on the values in database which do get updated randomly after every 5 seconds. I have tried with mouse click, but what can be done if we want the colors to change automatically as the page refreshes after 5 seconds?

eg if the value retrieved from database is between 30-40 i want it to be blue

else 40-60 let it be green 
and 60-70 be it red in color

```
else
{
header( "refresh:5;url=temperature.php" );
mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE sensor SET stemp=ROUND(RAND() * 40) + 30");

$res=mysqli_query($con,"Select * from sensor where sid='s1'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    echo "<font color='#F87431'>.<h1>". $row['stemp']." is the temperature of first sensor "."<br>"."</h1>";

} 

?>
<html>
<body>

<h1>Department A</h1>

<img id="myImage" onclick="changeImage()" src="red.png" width="100" height="100">
<script>
function changeImage() {
var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
if (image.src.match("red")) {
    image.src = "blue.png";
} else {
    image.src = "red.png";
    }
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: so this isn't inherently a mysql question as you have that solved?

Comment: you can use ajax for that

Comment: Use onload event handler (if i understand your question correctly)... Also, since page is refreshed every 5 seconds, why javascript? Why you just don't change source with php, according to database value(s)?

Answer (score 0):

#### Option 1

Simply use a meta tag to refresh your page every 5 seconds. When it refreshes it will query the database again and get the current colors.

```
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='<?= $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>'" />
```

#### Option 2

Fetch the new colors using ajax. In jQuery, you can set an interval of 5 seconds and perform a certain action using that interval.

setInterval requires a function or executable code in string format.

```
setInterval($.ajax/*a reference to the ajax function*/,
    2000, {url: 'someurl', success: onSuccess, error: onError}
);
```